# Mirror a git repo in Go with git2go

Tags: git, go, libgit2

I'm trying to mirror a git repo as a part of some work a go service is doing. I assume I want to be using `git2go`, but I'm not committed to that; any solution will work.

The workflow I am trying to accomplish (implemented in bash) is:

```
git clone --bare git:github.com/foo/bar.git ./tmp/
cd ./tmp/
git push --mirror git:another-host/vendor/bar.git
```

Here's what I have so far:

`main.go`

```
package main

import (
        "log"

        git "gopkg.in/libgit2/git2go.v22"
)

func main() {
        src := "git://github.com/fliglio/web.git"
        dest := "http://foo:asdf@localhost:7990/scm/phpv/web.git"

        cloneOptions := &git.CloneOptions{
                Bare: true,
        }
        repo, err := git.Clone(src, "local", cloneOptions)
        if err != nil {
                log.Panic(err)
        }
        log.Print(repo)

        fork, err := repo.CreateRemote("upstream", dest)
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }

        refspecs, err := fork.FetchRefspecs()
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }
        err = fork.Push(refspecs, &git.PushOptions{}, &git.Signature{Name: "ben", Email: "benschw@gmail.com"}, "msg")
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }

}
```

This is cloning the bare repo fine, but I think I may be headed in the wrong direction for pushing that to the new location

Here is the output when run:

```
17:02:12 &{0x2655b50}
panic: Not a valid reference 'refs/heads/*'

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
        /home/ben/go/src/github.com/benschw/composer-sync/main.go:33  +0x47a

goroutine 17 [syscall, locked to thread]:
runtime.goexit()
        /opt/go1.5.2/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1721 +0x1
```

Comment: I've tried `git2go` and gotten as far as creating a bare clone. the "push" aspect is throwing me for a loop, I can't figure out from the godocs how to go about pushing all branches/tags and I can't find other examples to work from

Comment: Then it might be a good idea to show some code that you have tried so far. The question as it currently is looks like you want to find some who writes the code for you.

Comment: gotcha, thanks. I'll try to rope together what I have so far